# Read file with progress bar in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, macos, cocoa, grand-central-dispatch

I'd like to create a progress bar showing the status of a file reading.
I read the file using a C++ class Reader that contains a variable _progress.

How can I tell to Cocoa to update the progress bar with the value of reader._progress without writing any ObjC code in the Reader class?

Any help would be appreciated.

```
ProgressController *pc = [[ProgressController alloc] init];
[pc showWindow:sender];


// Create the block that we wish to run on a different thread
void (^progressBlock)(void);
progressBlock = ^{
    [pc.pi setDoubleValue:0.0];
    [pc.pi startAnimation:sender];

    Reader reader("/path/to/myfile.txt");
    reader.read();

    while (reader._progress < 100.)
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [pc.pi setDoubleValue:reader._progress];
            [pc.pi setNeedsDisplay:YES];
        });
    }
}; // end of progressBlock

// Finally, run the block on a different thread
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0);
dispatch_async(queue, progressBlock);
```

---

So here is my second try.

The reader code:

```
class PDBReader
{
public:
Reader(const char *filename);
Reader(string filename);
~Reader();

int read();

string _filename;
float _progress;

void setCallback(void (^cb)(double))
{
    if (_cb)
    {
        Block_release(_cb);
        _cb = Block_copy(cb);
    }
}
void (^_cb)(double);

protected:
private:
};



int Reader::read()
{
string buffer;
unsigned atomid = 0;
ifstream file;
file.open(_filename.c_str(), ifstream::in);

if (!file.is_open())
{
    return IOERROR;
}

file.seekg(0, ios_base::end);
float eof = (float) file.tellg();
file.seekg(0, ios_base::beg);

while (getline(file, buffer))
{
    _progress = (float) file.tellg() / eof * 100.;
    if (_cb)
    {
        _cb(_progress);
    }
        // some more parsing here...
    }
file.close();
return SUCCESS;
}

PDBReader::~PDBReader()
{
if (_cb)
{
    Block_release(_cb);
}
}
```

And the Cocoa part:

```
-(IBAction) test:(id) sender
{
ProgressController *pc = [[ProgressController alloc] init];
[pc showWindow:sender];

Reader reader("test.txt");

reader.setCallback(^(double progress) 
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [pc.pi setDoubleValue:progress]; 
        [pc.pi setNeedsDisplay:YES];
    });
});

reader.read();
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What problem(s) are you seeing when using the code you've posted?

Comment: the main problem is that is doesn't work! at all I mean! Basically it's seems to be in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally!!!!!

It work's well when do not put it into a queue.

```
ProgressController *pc = [[ProgressController alloc] init];
[pc showWindow:sender];
[pc.pi setUsesThreadedAnimation:YES];

Reader reader("test.txt");  
reader.setCallback(^(double progress) 
{
    [pc.pi setDoubleValue:progress]; 
    [pc.pi setNeedsDisplay:YES];
});

reader.read();
```

But why do you say "This is bad, though, because it blocks the main thread"?
Because basically my program has to wait the file to be read before doing anything else.
Is there some basic optimization I miss here?

Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: Why did you post your own answer and accept it rather than mine?

Answer (score 7):

Just because you don't want to make Reader include Objective-C code doesn't mean you can only observe it from the outside.  It can call a C function via a passed-in function pointer.  It can use a more general functor (function object) mechanism.  It can even take a block.

You definitely don't want to do that `while (reader._progress < 100.)` loop.  That's a busy loop.  It will spin around updating the progress as fast as computerly possible.  It will peg a CPU core at 100% utilization.  In fact, it will probably queue tasks to the main dispatch queue faster than they can be run.

You only want to update the progress indicator when the Reader has updated its `_progress` member, which will require some sort of cooperation from the Reader class.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I came to this conclusion to but I don't know how to do that. Do you have a sample code to propose?

Comment: For example, create a `setCallback(void (^cb)(double))` member function on the `Reader` class.  Also create a `void (^_cb)(double)` member variable.  The setter would do `if (_cb) Block_release(_cb); _cb = Block_copy(cb);`.  Whenever `Reader` updates `_progress`, it should also do `if (_cb) _cb(_progress);`.  The destructor should also do `if (_cb) Block_release(_cb);`.

Comment: Thank you I'll try it and let you know.

Comment: Hum...I actually don't see how the code in the cocoa part should be constructed. Any help on that point please?

Comment: You'd do something like `reader.setCallback(^(double progress){ dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [pc.pi setDoubleValue:progress];
            [pc.pi setNeedsDisplay:YES];
        });});`

Comment: So this is the code I have in the Cocoa part. It compiles but the progress bar does not update (whereas the read is being). ProgressController *pc = [[ProgressController alloc] init];
 [pc showWindow:sender];
 Reader reader("myfile.txt");
 reader.setCallback(^(double progress) 
 {
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   [pc.pi setDoubleValue:progress]; 
   [pc.pi setNeedsDisplay:YES];
  });
 });

 reader.read();

Comment: Edit your question to add both this code and the Reader code.

Comment: In `setCallback()`, the release of the old block should be conditional on there being an old block, but the copy and assignment of the new block should be unconditional.

Comment: yes that's right but it doesn't change the fact that the progress bar is not updated in real time.

Comment: I had thought that either Reader worked asynchronously or you were using it on a background thread. If it's synchronous on the main thread then nothing you queue to the main dispatch queue is going to be processed until either a) you return control back to the frameworks (i.e. leave your function) or b) run the run loop in one of the common modes. However, if it's synchronous on the main thread, you don't have to queue anything. Have the callback just directly update the progress bar (set its value and then invoke `-display` on it). This is bad, though, because it blocks the main thread.